# How to display the elements in a Set that has integer values in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, set, hashset

My program is as follows:

```
private void removeElementsFromSecond(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) 
{
    List list1 = Arrays.asList(arr1);
    Set<Integer> set1 = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(list1);
    List list2 = Arrays.asList(arr2);
    Set<Integer> set2 = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(list2);
    set2.removeAll(set1);

    Iterator itr = set2.iterator();

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(itr.next());
    }
}
```

And the inputs are:

```
int[] arr1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
int[] arr2 = {0,1,2,3,4};
```

But the output is displayed as

```
[I@45bab50a
```

I came across this link while surfing

http://www.java-examples.com/iterate-through-elements-java-hashset-example

I guess I am doing more or less similar stuff here. 
Can anyone please help me to display the proper values?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Calling `Arrays.asList(arr1)` on an `int[]` array would produce a `List` whose single element is that array. That's why the `Set` has a single element, and printing it prints the array element.

Use `Integer[]` arrays instead.

```
private void removeElementsFromSecond(Integer[] arr1, Integer[] arr2) 
{
    List list1 = Arrays.asList(arr1);
    Set<Integer> set1 = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(list1);
    List list2 = Arrays.asList(arr2);
    Set<Integer> set2 = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(list2);
    set2.removeAll(set1);

    Iterator itr = set2.iterator();

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(itr.next());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. Doesnt autoboxing takes care of this?

Comment: there is no autobox from int[] to Integer[]

Comment: @user1407668 Arrays.asList expects one or more objects as input. When you pass it an array of primitives, there is only one object - the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
 private void removeElementsFromSecond(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        Set<Integer> set1 = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i : arr1) {
            set1.add(i);
        }
        Set<Integer> set2 = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i : arr2) {
            set2.add(i);
        }
        set2.removeAll(set1);

        Iterator<Integer> itr = set2.iterator();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List list1 = Arrays.asList(arr1);
```

This where the problem actually exists. `Arrays.asList(arr1)` Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array. And `List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(arr1);` raised class cast exception.

Write way to do this (using #java8)

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Collections.addAll(list1, Arrays.stream(arr1).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new));
...
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Collections.addAll(list2, Arrays.stream(arr2).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new));
```

If you are not using #java8 , then you need to create `Integer` array and and convert each and individual `int` to `Integer` and add them into array and convert it to `List`

```
Integer[] arryInt1 = new Integer[arr1.length];
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    arryInt1[i] = Integer.valueOf(arr1[i]);
}
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(arr1);
```

---

I think it would be better if use `Integer[]` itself as source then it would be much easier.

```
private void removeElementsFromSecond(Integer[] arr1, Integer[] arr2){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you could have used generics in your code and declared proper type you would have understood what's going on here. So if i use generics, i get as below:

```
private static void removeElementsFromSecond(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    List<int[]> list1 = Arrays.asList(arr1);
    //blah blah
}
```

See the definition of Arrays.asList [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

So in your case it's returning you List (assuming object of type arrays i.e. int[].class). When you need to work with collections you should use Object rather than primitives. So if you define your array like:

```
Integer[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
Integer[] arr2 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

and use those in your method as below:

```
private void removeElementsFromSecond(Integer[] arr1, Integer[] arr2) {
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(arr1);
    //blah blah
}
```

Then your code will work perfectly. As of now, each element of List will hold an array itself rather than individual elements within an array.

Answer (score 0):

Just modified a bit

```
private static void removeElementsFromSecond(Integer[] arr1, Integer[] arr2) {
    List list1 = Arrays.asList(arr1);
    Set<Integer> set1 = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(list1);
    List list2 = Arrays.asList(arr2);
    Set<Integer> set2 = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(list2);
    set2.removeAll(set1);
    Iterator itr = set2.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(itr.next());
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    Integer[] arr2 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    removeElementsFromSecond(arr1, arr2);
}
```

Arrays.asList(arr) will give a list of int[] and not int. Instead you should use Wrapper classes than primitives